# Django Rest Framework - Optimize Serializer with nested objects and @property on related Model

Tags: python, django, optimization, django-rest-framework, query-optimization

Let me explain briefly the context with some code.

Two related Models. One of them has a really expensive @property field:

```
# models.py

class MyModel(models.Model):
  [... fields ...]

class RelatedModel(models.Model):
   [... fields ...]
   related_field = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, ...)

   @property
   def expensive_query_field(self):
     return OtherModel.objects.filter(
           Q(some_field__some_relation__id=self.some_field_id) |
           Q(some_other_field__some_other_relation__id=self.some_other_field_id) |
           [...]
     ).distinct().order_by('-id')
```

On the serializer side those are mirrored:

```
# serializers.py

class RelatedModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  [... fields ...]
  expensive_query_field_objects = OtherModelSerializer(many=True)

class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  [... fields ...]
  related_field_objects = RelatedModelSerializer(many=True)
```

Everything works fine BUT it's really inefficient, since the `@property` is a python-land thinghy and it's also querying off an unrelated Model I can't really `prefetch_related` or `select_related` to reduce the number of queries.
Thus, when serializing an instance of `MyModel`, I end up with N expensive queries (with N equal to the number of RelatedModel connected to MyModel).

I'm looking for optimization ideas to avoid the N+1 queries.

I've tried, in `MyModelSerializer.to_representation()`, to manually pre-fetch all expensive queries in one go for all RelatedModel and then unpack the data directly into `Queryset._result_cache` but don't want to go so low-level as it makes code more fragile and I'm not even sure it might work :(

Comment: Is the `expensive_query_field` completely unrelated to the `RelatedModel.related_field`? If they are related in the db, there may be some orm optimizations for the queryset used by the view. Otherwise, you'll have to rely on caching.

Comment: Any reason you cannot add a foreign key relation to `OtherModel` in your `RelatedModel` ?

Comment: @damon it's not *entirely* unrelated but the models are several JOINS apart and the expensive query is much more complex than the example using many "sourcing starting points" models to retrieve the final list of objects. I tried to "cargo-cult" add as many 'prefetch_related' relationships as possible but I believe the ORM won't recognize them due to the nature of `@property`.

Comment: @Daniel we get to OtherModel through several different JOIN "chains" from several different "starting points", adding a direct relationship won't be practical. I eventually prefer to precompute the data and store it denormalized directly in a supporting table and use signals to update it.

Comment: It's hard to know what's possible without seeing the actual fields and models that would be linked through the `JOIN` statements.